# JavaScript Unable to get value returned from a then() call to another then() call

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, promise

I am trying to execute this code:

```
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
    const user = this;
    const access = 'auth';
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toHexString(), access}, 'abc123');

    user.tokens.push({access, token});

    user.save().then(() => {
        return token;
    });
};
```

In my express file, I have following code:

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    const user = new User(body);

    user.save().then(() => {
        return user.generateAuthToken();
    }).then((token) => {
        res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});
```

The problem is that the token returned from the `user.save().then()` call in first file never reaches the express code `user.generateAuthToken()`. What is the reason and how should I solve it?

Comment: Why save in the `generateAuthToken()` method? By leaving out the `user.save()` side effect and simply returning `token`, a single `.save()` back in the post handler will do all the saving you need. And as a bonus, your promise chaining issue will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`generateAuthToken` has no `return` statement.

If you want to return the promise that `then` returns, then you have to do so explicitly.

Comment: Then where should I exactly add return statement?

Comment: At the front of the last statement in the function. (i.e. the expression that you call `then()` in).

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your schema to the following:

```js
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
    const user = this;
    const access = 'auth';
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toHexString(), access}, 'abc123');

    user.tokens.push({access, token});

    user.save().then(() => {
        return token;
    });
};
```

The generateAuthToken does not return a Promise in your code